# In Drupal front-end, menu drop-down hierarchy not displaying

Tags: drupal

The Drupal webiste I'm working on: [http://student17.cas181s.com/project](http://student17.cas181s.com/project/)

I have a menu dropdown, with menu items that have children, I've already check-boxed the "show as expanded" for literally all my menu items. Visitors viewing my front-end cannot see **[this](http://oi61.tinypic.com/bf0r2c.jpg)** (only I can see this, in back-end, as admin). Why is this? I'm using Bartik 7.34 theme.

Answer (score 0):

Check out privilages for anonymous user for that content that your friends cant see. In drupal if someone can't see page content he won't see link to that page also. Maku sure that pages are published - admin can see all the content but most of the user groups only published one. At end...clear the cache.